# What is the difference between the data link layer and link layer?

Tags: networking, protocols, data-link-layer

What is the difference between the data link layer and link layer? Do they mean the same thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite the different semantics of layering in TCP/IP and OSI, **the link layer is often described as a combination of the data link layer and the physical layer in the Open Systems Interconnection (OSI) protocol stack.**

The link layer of the TCP/IP model is often compared directly with the combination of the data link layer and the physical layer in the Open Systems Interconnection (OSI) protocol stack. Although they are congruent to some degree in technical coverage of protocols, **they are not identical**. The link layer in TCP/IP is still wider in scope and in principle a different concept and terminology of classification.

Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_layer)

Answer (score 3):

In the frame work of the TCP/IP ([Internet Protocol Suite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_protocol_suite)) model, OSI's [data link layer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_link_layer), in addition to other components, is contained in TCP/IP's lowest layer, the [link layer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_layer). The Internet Protocol's link layer only concerns itself with hardware issues to the point of obtaining hardware addresses for locating hosts on a physical network link and transmitting data frames onto the link. Thus, the link layer is broader in scope and encompasses all methods that affect the local link, which is the group of connections that are limited in scope to other nodes on the local access network.

Link layer is the lowest component layer of the Internet protocols, as TCP/IP is designed to be hardware independent. While, Data link layer is 2nd layer of OSI model.

Answer (score 2):

**Data Link Layer:** 
The data link layer handles communication between systems on the same local network.

**Link Layer:**
The Link Layer is a link between the physical and logical network.